# Ivy publish to repository doesn't update local cache

Tags: hudson, ivy, dependency-management

Given:

- Building using Hudson/Ant.
- Ivy cache timeout is set to 5 min.
- Ivy repository contains has Project A version 2.2.2 and Project B version 1.1.1.
- Project B relies on Project A.

Events:

1. API change is made to Project A.
2. Related changes are made to Project B.
3. Project A version 2.2.3 is built and published to the repository.
4. Under 5 minutes later, Project B version 1.1.2 is built.
5. Project B fails, still pulling in Project A version 2.2.2 from the Ivy Cache.
6. After 5 minutes, Project B will build correctly, with Project A version 2.2.3

I've looked but don't see an obvious solution (except not caching?). Is there a setting on publish that will update the local cache and the repo? Do you need to explicitly publish to both?

Answer (score 0):

Just speculation: if A and B are built on the same machine, would doing an <ivy:resolve refresh="true"> at the end of A's build refresh the cache?  That doesn't help if A and B build on separate machines, of course...

Comment: I think you missed a key word in there "doing an [?] at the end" which is very cliffhanger.

Comment: @Instantsoup: sorry, I forgot to escape the angle brackets.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

One solution, similar to (but not as bad as) not caching is to decrease the time things live in the cache via setting the following ivy property:

```
ivy.cache.ttl.default                 = 30s
```

Maybe that would fix your problem, for now.  Although, it's not much better than not caching.

Off the top of my head, another thing I might try is to turn off caching but then re-implement caching manually by creating a filesystem resolver in your ivy settings file that **points to the cache** and placing it lower on the chain.  That would look something like this:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="all-repositories" />
    <include file="ivysettings-common.xml" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="all-repositories" returnFirst="true" >
            ...
            <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true" />
            <filesystem name="manual-cache">
                <ivy pattern="${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}/cache/${ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern}" />
                <artifact pattern="${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}/cache/${ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern}" />
            </filesystem>
            ...
        </chain>    
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Note: that *ivy.default.ivy.user.dir*, *ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern* and *ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern* are built-in properties that are set by default.  I'm referencing them here in this example but I wouldn't need to make any other special effort to set them (they contain proper default values, already).

I hope one of these approaches can address your issue.  Those are the only two possible solutions that come to mind, right now.

Answer (score 0):

In the ivy file of project B you need to set the changing attribute to true on the dependency.

> ```
>   <dependency org="org.example" name="A" revision="latest.integration" changing="true" />
> ```

[See the ivy documentation](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html)